# UI not updating in flutter after pop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

Hello there hope you all are doing well. Coming to the point I am developing a weather application in flutter its working fine but when it comes to getting weather by city its not working actually its getting all the data but not updating data in UI.

**Updating UI**

```
void updateUI(var weatherData) {
   if (weatherData == null) {
     city = '';
     temperature = 0;
     weatherMessage = 'Unable to fetch data';
   }
   id = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
   weatherIcon = weatherModel.getWeatherIcon(id);
   city = weatherData['name'];
   double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
   temperature = temp.toInt();
   weatherMessage = weatherModel.getMessage(temperature);
   description = weatherData['weather'][0]['description'];
 }
```

**Recieving city name**(Here is the actual problem i guess)

```
FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      dynamic typedname = await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Cityscreen()));

                      setState(
                        () async {
                          dynamic weatherData =
                              await weatherModel.getCityLocation(typedname);
                          updateUI(weatherData);
                        },
                      );
                    },
```

**Getting city location**

```
Future<dynamic> getCityLocation(String cityname) async
  {
    Network_helper network_helper=Network_helper('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$cityname&appid=$key');
    var weatherData=await network_helper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }
```

**City screen stateful widget**

```
class _CityscreenState extends State<Cityscreen> {
  late String cityName;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/back1.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration,
                  onChanged: (value)
                  {
                    cityName=value;
                  },
                ),

              ),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context,cityName);
                  },
                child: Text(
                  'Get weather',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see the function `updateUI` inside `_CityscreenState` being triggered, which I supposed is in the widget where pop will get you in, I see that you need to do either a callback inside  `_CityscreenState` which will trigger `updateUI` in the other widget, or use a state management  solution to update the state globally.

Comment: thats because the city screen will remain the same it will just pop by returning a string that is basically a city name and that cityname is passed to get city location and then simply making a call to updateUI and i had tried all the printing everything works great but the only problem is my UI is not updating

Comment: please add the code where you get the pop value.

Comment: first have a look at city screen(city screen stateful widget) there its poping the value in the flat button the look at receiving cityname there its receiving that string and storing it in typedname

Comment: In `Recieving city name` did you print if the value `typedname`  is coming, just before the setState?

Comment: yes everything working fine i had printed each and everything the cityname before it pop and typed name after it pop and even print the updated cityname in the getUI method everything works fine the only problem is UI is not updating

Answer (score 0):

Use setstate in **then** section in **navigation push** code.

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Cityscreen())).then((value) {
  setState(() async {
    dynamic weatherData =
                              await weatherModel.getCityLocation(typedname);
                          updateUI(weatherData);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If [answer by Laxman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74415829/18645340) doesn't work well try separating setState and async code...

you can call getCityLocation() store value in a temp variable and then call setState() on assignment.

Some reference to back my answer [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358961/flutter-dart-setstate-does-not-reload-state-when-using-with-future-for-the)